# Drag & drop displaced

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, imageview

I've been writing a simple app using drag & drop, wich works fine, except for a little detail. When I hold for first time the ImageView that contains the drag action, the DragShadowBuilder places the miniature view on a wrong place. The weirdest part is that later, it fixes itself, and operation continues perfectly well.
This is a image showing the behavior (I'm holding the Contacts app icon, and see where the thumbnail is)

[image: displaced]

This is the code I use

```
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recent_entry, null);
        ImageView img = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.recent_icon);

        img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
                if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
                    view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, null, 0);
                    mLaunchIntent = holder.getLaunchIntent();
                    mSelectedItem = view;
                    mRecentDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Purely a guess, but should you not be using the location of the drag source, and not the view that contains the drag content?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit your answer?, I'm not native english speaker and didn't understand it. You mean that I should add the drag handler not to the imageview but to it's parent?

Comment: Looking more are the documentation, it appears you have to set the touch location for the drag image. This locates the drag image relative to the mouse location. See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html